# Auto resize window content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, autosize

When debugging my WPF programs I have noticed that when the window is the set size, the contols look just fine. But when the window is maximized, the content is positioned at the same place as if window has not resized. I want it so that the content and window resize proportionately. How can I do this? Sorry if it is a noobish question, but I'm kinda new in the WPF era.

---

The XAML code is not completely ready yet but here is some of elements:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    ...
    </StackPanel>

    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Right">
    ...
    </TabControl>

    <ListView>
    ...
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: first rule of all WPF question, "Post thy XAML"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this is because dimension values are set statically, rather than dynamically. Here's the static approach:

```
<RowDefinition x:Name="NavigatorRow" Height="120"/>
<RowDefinition x:Name="TaskPanelRow" Height="80"/>
```

Both rows will have fixed heights, and they won't resize with the window.

Here is the dynamic approach:

```
<RowDefinition x:Name="NavigatorRow" Height="1*"/> 
<RowDefinition x:Name="TaskPanelRow" Height="80"/>
```

The bottom row still has a fixed height of 80, but the top row will expand to fill whatever space is available. In other words, the rows will resize with the window. Columns work the same way.

If I had three rows, I could do this:

```
<RowDefinition x:Name="NavigatorRow" Height="1*"/>
<RowDefinition x:Name="CalendarRow" Height="2*"/>
<RowDefinition x:Name="TaskPanelRow" Height="80"/>
```

The Navigator Row and the Calendar Row will share the available space, with the Calendar Row taking twice the height of the Navigator Row. You get the idea.

So, it's not the container you use, but how you size that container. The one exception, as noted above, is the StackPanel, which does not scale. Use a Grid instead, since it does scale.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is because the content is hosted in a container which has an explicitly set width and height - like Grid for example.

Post your Xaml or that answer is the best you will get!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using StackPanels they don't resize dynamically properly.

Ideally you should use a grid and specify percentages if you want things to resize proportionately.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why everyone is saying stackpanels don't resize dynamically. They handle resizing just like grids do. Just make sure you set your HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" (and/or VerticalAlignment) and the content will expand to fill the stackpanel size. I'm currently using a UI that consists of many nested stackpanels, horizontal and vertical resizing the window expands/contracts all the controls equally inside the window.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to have some sort of container for your controls, right? If you're using Canvas and just position your controls absolutely inside there you're pretty much out of luck; this isn't very well for scaling interfaces.

However, there are various container controls that will layout whatever you put in them in certain ways. And if used properly, they scale with a resizing window, too. The Grid is pretty flexible, but StackPanel and DockPanel are very handy at times, too.

You can nest them, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPF grid with the Widht and Height properties setupped with the "Number*" notion.
For example **Width="0.6*"**, wich is not absolute height but proportional relation to the container. Generaly , if you want resizable content, avoid the fixed size properties as much as you can.

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>                       
       <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Good Luck.